# How to store log messages to specific log file using symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, monolog

I am new to symfony2, how to store log messages to specific file i read the documentation but i am not understanding please help me any one i configured my config.yml file is:

```
# app/config/config.yml
monolog:
handlers:
    filter_for_errors:
        type: fingers_crossed
        # if *one* log is error or higher, pass *all* to file_log
        action_level: error
        handler: file_log

    # now passed *all* logs, but only if one log is error or higher
    file_log:
        type: stream
        path: "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log"

    # still passed *all* logs, and still only logs error or higher
    syslog_handler:
        type: syslog
        level: error
```

and config_dev file

```
# app/config/config_dev.yml
    monolog:
    handlers:
    main:
        type:  rotating_file
        path:  '%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log'
        level: debug
        # max number of log files to keep
        # defaults to zero, which means infinite files
        max_files: 10
```

if i trying to store log messages using

```
   $logger = $this->get('logger');
   $logger->info('I just got the logger');
```

here stores log messages to dev.log file, how to store log messages to easyrecrue.log specific file
Thanks for advance

Comment: `how to store log messages to easyrecrue.log specific file` - could you explain?

Comment: How can I log messages from my controllers, model to a specific log file ? instead of dev.log file i want to store easyrecrue.log file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you can create handlers for specific logging channels ([like here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/logging/channels_handlers.html#switching-a-channel-to-a-different-handler)) to store logs in different files.

You also need to define [your own logging channels](http://symfony.com/doc/current/logging/channels_handlers.html#creating-your-own-channel).

Monolog bundle will create services for every channel in a `monolog.logger.%your_channel%` format.

Comment: Thanks for reply, here any bundle installation is needed?

Comment: No, everything is in monolog-bundle config, included in symfony standard edition.